# Calling a C dll from C# windows application causes the svchost.exe to crash

Tags: c#, c++, string, dll, pinvoke

I created a `C DLL` so that I can use it in my `C#` application.
I tested the `DLL` on a `C++` test application and it worked fine, but it won't work in the C# application.
For some reason, I can't build a debug version of the `DLL`, and therefore I haven't been able to run the `C#` app in debug mode either.
The `DLL` debug configuration won't find the `include directories`, where as in the release mode, it works just fine!
I need to say that, there is a specific method which I give below, that causes the crash, calling the other methods from the `DLL` is fine and works as expected. 
This is the main implementation :
header definition:

```
//use this function to classify an image
CDLL_API const char* Classify(const char* img_path, int N = 2);
```

.cpp implementation

```
CDLL_API const char* Classify(const char * img_path, int N)
    {
        auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());
        std::vector<PredictionResults> result = classifier->Classify(std::string(img_path), N);
        std::string str_info = "";
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (size_t i = 0; i <result.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto label = result[i].label;
            auto acc = result[i].accuracy;
            ss << "label=" << label << ",acc=" << acc << "|";
        }
        return ss.str().c_str();
    }
```

C# code :

```
[DllImport(@"CDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern string Classify([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string img_path,int N = 2);

//...
        var s = Classify(txtFilePath.Text, 2);
        MessageBox.Show(s);
```

So I'm completely out of thoughts about what could be the real cause.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `CallingConvention.Cdecl` rather than `CallingConvention.StdCall`?

Comment: @stuartd: This is actually from a code I wrote several years ago, and I dont remember why I chose Cdecl instead of StdCall! by the way StdCall has the same issue when I tested it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you specified the calling convention to `Cdecl` (`CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`) in your C# PInvoke declaration; since this is the default calling convention in C++ code as well, you shouldn't have any calling convention mismatch in this case. Although, please note that the common calling convention for C-interface DLLs is [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx).

The problem I see is the way you return the string from the C-interface API

> ```
> CDLL_API const char* Classify(const char * img_path, int N)
> {
>     ...
>     return ss.str().c_str();
> }
> ```

(BTW I assume `ss` is something like a `std::ostringstream` object.)

You build a string using an output string stream (calling its `str` method), then you get a raw C-style string pointer calling `c_str`. But when the function exits, the string object is destroyed, so the C-style raw string pointer is not valid anymore.

To return a string from C-interface DLL APIs to C#, you can consider one of these options:

1. **Return a `BSTR` string** from the C-interface DLL. Use [`SysAllocString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx) to create the `BSTR` object from a raw C-style string pointer. Note that `BSTR`s "naturally" store **Unicode UTF-16** encoded strings, so please make sure to convert your string to this encoding. The CLR is able to manage `BSTR` strings just fine, so you don't have to pay attention to release the string memory: this will be the CLR's job.
2. Add to the C-interface DLL function a couple of parameters: a **pointer to a buffer**, and a **buffer size**. This will be an **output string buffer**, that is allocated by the caller (e.g. C#), and the C-interface API exported from the DLL will write the result string to that caller-provided buffer. This is what e.g. the `GetWindowText` Win32 API does (on the C# side, the output string buffer can be represented by a `StringBuilder` object).

Answer (score 2):

The `string` type in C# is not compatible with `const char *` in C. You have to use `StringBuilder`:

```
 [DllImport("aCDLL.dll")]
 public extern static void getabuilder(StringBuilder abuilder);
```

and in C dll:

```
 extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall getabuilder(char *abuilder);
```

If you do not like the StringBuilder, you can store the string characters in an array of `byte` initialised in C# and passed to the C function:

```
 [DllImport("aCDLL.dll")]
 public extern static void getastring(byte[] data, ref int datalength);
```

and in C:

```
 extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall getastring(const char *data, int *datalength);
```